# I need to count the number of times an argument is being passed to a shell script

Tags: shell

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash 

read –p “Enter the number you seek  “ NUM 

for VALUE in $@; do 

if [ $VALUE –eq $NUM ]; then COUNT=$((COUNT+1)); fi 

Done 

echo $NUM appeared $COUNT times
```

I run the script passing it the list of numbers 5 10 6 12 5 18 10 4 19 21 5 12 18 22 i get this error message:

[image]

Could you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You fixed what you did wrong in the question: you got rid of the space between `$` and `((`.

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net to fix various other issues as well.